# проблема с применяемым стилям

Tags: css, html5, css3

Стили не применяются на остальные картинки в дивах, только на картинки последнего таба. Как правильно прописать селекторы и почему  классы к картинкам не работают.

```
#table .imga {
  clear: both;
}


#table div  img {
  width: 144px;
  opacity: .7;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

#table div  img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#table >div{
  margin-top: 50px;
 position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}



<div id="table">
    <div >
        <img src="005.png">
        <img src="006.png">
        <img src="007.png">
        <img src="008.png">
    </div>
    <div >
        <img src="005.png">
        <img src="006.png">
        <img src="007.png">
        <img src="008.png">
    </div>
    <div >
        <img src="005.png">
        <img src="006.png">
        <img src="007.png">
        <img src="008.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="005.png">
        <img src="006.png">
        <img src="007.png">
        <img src="008.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

[ссылка на код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLvKNb)

Comment: Вы ссылку специально поломали?

Comment: Да , не получалось так вставить по примеру. Задавал отступы но не проходило.

Comment: Попробуйте еще раз. Если не получится форматирование - Вам помогут.

Comment: я хотел сказать: попробуйте вставить код в Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Там все работает. но вот с позиционированием вы намудрили.
position:absolute; - склеил все дивы в одну область. Если что инспектите сразу фаербагом или что там у вас. Все дивы было видно. И стоило бы сразу контейнер с дивами разместить типа

```
#table{
position:absolute;
margin-top:50px;
}
```

а потом уже позиционировать дивы внутри.
Возможно стоит освежить кое какие знания по позиционированию. Немного поправил, надеюсь дальше разберетесь)

Upd: И с картинками все работает. немного почистил от мусора, которому сразу не придал значения. Ибо искал что там с дивами было. А классов к картинкам у вас нет если что) вы к ним просто как к элементам обращаетесь. И чисто ради интереса - а почему везде используете Id а не class?

[Поправленый код](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeqPzR)

Первый вариант трогать не буду, вдруг пригодится кому. А теперь по теме. 
Вот доработаный вариант, кажется должно быть так, как хотелось. Идея муторная, конечно, но все же реализуемая. Чтобы елементы работали, они должны находится в одном блоке. Если рисунки поместить еще в один div, то все фокус с display:none; не проходит. 
Если даже в вашем варианте добавить класс к диву - все эффекты работают, но есть одно НО - с вашим кодом вы прогружаете сразу все div и они накладываются друг на друга благодаря position:absolute;, поэтому стили работают только на последнем, потому что он загружен самым верхним и перекрывает дивы, которые находятся под ним. Если его закомментить, то будет работать 3 набор рисунков, второй и первый нет и так далее.

[Попытка номер 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGwRqE)

Comment: Нет , они не должны идти в одной вкладке. каждая четверка картинок в отдельной вкладке. То есть с позиционированием все правильно или я в чем то не прав ?

Comment: Вы хотели чтобы при переключении вкладок менялись картинки? Они у вас и так - каждая четверка картинок в отдельный див засунута. Что вы имеете ввиду под вкладками?

Comment: Сейчас объясню. Да , там разные картинки но им всем заданны свойство opacity. Когда из четырёх дивов заполнен только один , то  он имеет свойство opacity: 1 при наведении ( по дефолту стоит opacity: 0.7) и это мне и нужно на всех дивах. Но когда я заполняю все дивы , то только последний из них имеет стили при наведении . Мне нужно  чтобы это правило выполнялось на всех изображениях всех дивов.

Comment: я могу с этим справиться вставив просто каждый див в отдельный iframe , но мне интересен способ по легче и почему когда я добавляю класс к картинкам то :hover эффекты не работают

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, код по второй ссылке

Comment: Спасибо большое , очень помогли. Уже думал на iframe все ставить.

Comment: Есть ещё пару вопросов , в интернете трудно на них найти ответ , если бы могли поговорить где-то в лс то отпишитесь мне пожалуйста . Буду очень признателен .

Comment: @НикитаУрсу в моем профиле есть ссылка на Вк, либо стукните на почту anlockout собака гмейл